# Should I use 'the' before 'same'?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Please explain to me.
I am so confused with these two words.
What I should use, 'same' or 'the same' in the following sentence?

> The amount of time to melt was **same**
>
> The amount of time to melt was **the same**.

Comment: In your example sentence, you would use _the same_: _'The amount of time to melt was **the same**._ Much more often than not, that's the form you would use: _They drove the same car. Linda bought the same dress as Betty. Those two birds are the same color. We are taking two of the same classes next semester. Your son was born in the same hospital where my mother died. Those two players were rookies in the same year. Multiplying any number by zero give the same result._ In **all** those examples, removing the word "the" from "the same" would make the sentence sound incorrect.

Comment: By the way, I'm a little surprised this question got closed. It's interesting the way the word _same_ has the word "the" paired with it so often. It's a very interesting question to ponder.

Comment: I nominated it to come back.  Perhaps we can answer it again if we get one more taker.

Comment: (I knew nothing about the last time this question got closed.) I voted to close this question because I think my old answer should answer it. (See also: ["The same name" vs "a same name": what's the difference?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/11665/3281)). Feel free to reject the suggested duplicate if you think the old answers cannot answer this question.